# Single answer is Community Wiki while the rest are not

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, community-wiki, answers

Under the link [XML string manipulation in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084476/xml-string-manipulation-in-js) a single answer is Community Wiki while the rest are not (the lower one in the image)...

> [image: bug]

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When posting an answer, there's a "Community wiki" checkbox for making that particular answer CW, even if the whole question is not. I believe this is not a bug.

Perhaps the answerer thought that he doesn't need to get rep for that specific answer, or wanted to make it more easily editable for the community. Or he simply misunderstood what Community wiki meant.

Answer (score 4):

Often times people will mark a particular answer as Community Wiki to prevent themselves from receiving the negative effect of downvotes. This tends to be whenever you are posting that is rather sarcastic or more joking than anything else.